# Swift 3: Swipe to 'Flag', how to

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have some code which in essence works fine. I get to see the flag button when I swipe left, the string "Flag button tapped" is printed to the console when I tap the button. So the basics are in place.

But... I want to mark the cell as "Flagged" instead of just printing it to the console. Pretty much like the Apple mail app on an Iphone,

I use this function to create the swipe button:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt
indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

let flag = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Flag") {
action, index in

    print("Flag button tapped")

    }
    flag.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    return [flag]
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Any input would be welcome.

Comment: In Mail it's just an image on the left side of the cell which is shown / hidden depending on the flagged state. Add an appropriate boolean property to your model change the value in the row action and reload the row in the table view. In `cellForRow` show / hide the image view depending on the boolean property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add one `round view` in your cell on left most side. then you can set it's color based on your requirement. If you flag some row then set this view's background color to orange, and if it is not flagged then set it's background color to clear color!